# Can i change my project name in Xcode while Apple reject me coz my app's name is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have done all things with my old name , but Apple ask me to change it , but can I change it? I am afraid that everything will messed up after I change my name , coz all related to this project name , so what can I do , actually I do not know if I can change , I am just afraid , Can anyone tell me if I can change my app name in Xcode and if there will be something messed up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name of the app without affecting the name of the project or the code.

I am making the assumption you just want the app display name different, so here is how to do it:

1. Go to your Project Settings and Select Target
2. Next you can move across and select Info

[image: where to look]

3. Right click anywhere in the table and select add row. It will come up with some options - type **"Bundle"** and it will display the option **Bundle display name**. You need to select that.

[image: add row]

4. On that line,click the right of the row and add your new name.

[image]

This will not affect your code and will only change the display name of the app. Now you have a new display name without effecting the main bundle.

Comment: Apple should agree this time

Comment: Yes. I would also ensure that in your application, anywhere you have made a label with the old name is also changed. Apple do not like misleading or confusing labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change the name Apple won't publish it on the App Store. I think it's an easy choice.

You don't need to change your *project* name. You don't need to change the *bundle* name. Just the external name of the app. It's a really small change.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of my XCode]

1. From the Navigator click the XCode project
2. Click "Build settings"
3. Click the search field and type `product_name`
4. Change the Product name to a new one

Repeat for every target you have.